# What is the problem in my code? How to delete a collection from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete a collection from mongodb using postmap API. Below is my code.The update function is working fine.But, delete function isn't working. It's displaying internal server error.I dont know why?

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
//uodate
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    if ((req.body.userId === req.params.id) || req.body.isAdmin) {
        if (req.body.password) {
            try {
                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
            }
            catch (err) {
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }
        }
        try {
            const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                $set: req.body,
            });
           return res.status(200).json("Account has been updated");
        }
        catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }
    else return req.status(400).json("You can only update your account!!!");
});
//delete
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    if ((req.body.userId === req.params.id) || req.body.isAdmin) {
        try {
           await User.deleteOne(req.params.id);
            return res.status(200).json("Account has been deleted");
        }
        catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }
    else return res.status(400).json("You can only update your account!!!");
});



module.exports = router;
```

Help me with this[postman API screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGCyq.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
await User.deleteOne({_id:req.params.id});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `deleteOne()` method. If you want to delete whole collection, you should use `deleteMany()` method:

```js
await User.deleteMany({});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Model.deleteOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-deleteOne) method expects a filter object, like `{name: "value'"}`.  You are passing `req.params.id` which is a string.  If you dig out the full text of the error, it will likely complain about that string not being an object.

You probably meant to use the [Model.findByIdAndDelete](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findByIdAndDelete) method like

```
await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
```